# Contrapositive of statement regarding open sets

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, propositional-calculus

I am taking a Real Analysis class and i am having problems with the following:

"A set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is open $\Leftrightarrow$ the following holds: if a sequence $\left(x_{n}\right)$ converges to a point $a \in A$, then $x_{n} \in A$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ sufficiently large"

I am trying to prove $(\Leftarrow)$. I think i can prove the contrapositive statement. However, **i am not sure how to properly write the statement in the contrapositive form.**

**Attempt 1 to write the contrapositive:**
If $A \in \mathbb{R}$ is not open, then there exists a sequence $\left(x_{n}\right)$ such that $\lim x_{n}=a$ and $\mathrm{x}_{\mathrm{n}} \notin \mathrm{A}$.

**Attempt 2 to write the contrapositive:**
If $A \in \mathbb{R}$ is not open, then there exists a sequence $\left(x_{n}\right)$ such that $\lim x_{n}$ is not equal to $a$ and $\mathrm{x}_{\mathrm{n}} \notin \mathrm{A}$.

Why should (or should not) the statement $\lim x_{n}=a$ be negated?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of them is quite right, even apart from the use of $\in$ instead of $\subseteq$ at the beginning of each of them. A correct statement of the contrapositive is:

> If $A\subseteq\Bbb R$ is not open, then there is a sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $\Bbb R$ that converges to a point $a\in A$, but for each $m\in\Bbb N$ there is an $n\ge m$ such that $x_n\notin A$.

Equivalently, one could say:

> If $A\subseteq\Bbb R$ is not open, then there is a sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $\Bbb R$ that converges to a point $a\in A$ but has infinitely many terms that are not in $A$.

Comment: Why the sequence still converges to a point $a \in A$ even even though we are negating the statement? I cant figure that out.

Comment: @Lucas: The implication whose contrapositive you want has the form $(p\to q)\to r$, where $p$ is ‘$\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a sequence converging to a point $a\in A$’, $q$ is ‘$x_n\in A$ for all sufficiently large $n\in\Bbb N$, and ‘$A$ is open’. The contrapositive is $\neg r\to\neg(p\to q)$, and $\neg(p\to q)$ is logically equivalent to $p\land\neg q$.

Comment: I suppose you meant $x_n$ and not $a_n$ at the end of the first formulation of the contrapositive?

Comment: @JackLeGrüß: I did indeed; thanks!